# rsync exclude files depending on --exclude position

Tags: rsync

I have a simple `rsync` script for sync source and test files:

```
rsync -a --include '*/' --include '*.hpp' --include '*.cpp' --include "Test/*" --exclude 'main.cpp'  --exclude 'makefile' --exclude '*' --progress . somewhere/
```

While it correctly excludes `makefile` it does not exclude `main.cpp`, while doing this:

```
rsync -a --include '*/' --exclude 'main.cpp' --include '*.hpp' --include '*.cpp' --include "Test/*"--exclude 'makefile' --exclude '*' --progress . somewhere/
```

Seems to work. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync):

> As  the  list  of  files/directories to transfer is built, rsync checks each name to be transferred against the list of include/exclude patterns in turn, and the first matching pattern is acted on:  if it is an exclude pattern, then that file is skipped; if it is an include pattern then that filename is not skipped; if no matching pattern is found, then the filename is not skipped.

So if you want `main.cpp` to be excluded, you need to have an `--exclude` pattern which matches `main.cpp` before any `--include` patterns which match it.

If you're using `--filter`, the same applies to that too. Actually `--include` and `--exclude` are just shorthand for certain kinds of `--filter` rules.